# MySQLの負荷テストツールを探しています

Tags: mysql, database

DBサーバのCPUとIOPSが、定められた非機能要求にてピーク時の負荷を乗り切るには、どのくらいの性能が必要なのかを負荷テストしたく、以下のことができる負荷テストツールを探しています。

- クエリを指定できる
  　 - JOINやWHERE句なども再現したいため、自分でクエリを指定できる必要があります。
- 同時接続数を指定できる
- クエリの頻度を指定できる
  　 - 1秒に110回送るクエリ、20秒に1回送るクエリなどが存在するため、クエリの頻度を指定できる必要があります。
- 検証時間を指定できる
  　 - 3分間検証を実施したいため。

以上、このようなことができる負荷ツールをご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら、ご教示いただけますと幸いです。
mysqlslapで行ける!と思ったのですが、どうやら「クエリの頻度を指定」することができないようで…。

自作でスクリプト組むのも非常に面倒なので、教えていただけるととても嬉しいです!

Comment: うーん……スクリプトを組まないってのが、どの程度なのか分からないので困りますが、ApacheのJmeterはアリでしょうか？

Comment: Jmeterで満たせそうです。ご教示いただきありがとうございます!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jmeterで出来そうとのことなので改めて回答します。
下記Jmeterの配布サイトになります。

http://jmeter.apache.org/

テスト計画とシナリオを作って負荷試験を行いログを出力すればよろしいかと思います。
また、試験に使用するテスト計画ファイル(`*.jmx`)を別のマシンで作成してから本番環境へ持っていくことも可能ですので、
本番環境でテスト計画ファイルを作成する前に試験環境でテスト計画を作成し、
テスト計画に不備が無いことを確認してから本番環境へ持っていくとよろしいかと思います。